# IXXAT Can library use in QT

Tags: qt, visual-c++, static-libraries, can-bus

I'm trying to use the IXXAT Can library ( delivered as an MSVC library ) in a Windows QT 5.4.0 project.

I've made a simple project , included the correct path and added the library in my .pro.
My application compiles without errors ( which is nice for a 3 lines code ) , linking is ok but the first call to an IXXAT library function throws a SIGSEV : Segmentation Fault.

I'm using MINGW 4.9.1 to compile , could that be the problem ?
Have you ever used that library ?

TIA

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compile the IXXAT library with MINGW as well.